# How to setup Keycloak client for Frontend?

Tags: django, django-rest-framework, keycloak, python-social-auth

I have included the [DRF-Social-OAuth2](https://github.com/wagnerdelima/drf-social-oauth2) library and set up the [Keycloak client for the Backend](https://python-social-auth.readthedocs.io/en/latest/backends/keycloak.html). Now I have to create a new public client for Frontend? If yes, what is the right way to do it?